# How rapidly does edit moderation occur?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

If I edit someone else's post I get a notice indicating that my edits will not be visible to others until they are checked by a moderator.  (In fact they disappear as soon as I leave the page and come back).  There is no indication when this might occur.  It seems as though these edits may be heading toward /dev/null.

1. When can a decision be expected?
2. Will I get notification if my edits are accepted?
3. Will I get notification if my edits are rejected?

In the case that comes to mind, I recently accepted an answer from another user because the answer hit the nail on the head conceptually as the right way to handle the situation.  However, it contained syntax errors.  I provided the fix by edit (providing it by comment would be ridiculous the way comments are formatted) and have heard nothing.

Comment: Don't worry, thanks to our local horde of review drones, your edits will be accepted in a few minutes even if they're incorrect.

Comment: Most awesome and truthful comment ever @FrédéricHamidi. I'm laughing, I'm crying, I'm giving it 5 stars.

Comment: Well, in my case that has not happened.

Comment: Yes it did, except that it has been rejected: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4677042

Comment: @Bart Wow, you found that right away.  I did not.  How did you find it?  That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Go to the activity tab in your profile. There you will find a link to your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I was looking for.  I do find it somewhat annoying that all the rejection replies were the same, as if auto-generated.  I wonder if any actual testing was done.  In my case my way works and the suggested way fails to execute.  This may possibly have something to do with different python versions, but then my original question specified 2.6.  And all this happened within a context of my ACCEPTING the answer as correct, so I think it's wrong to have said that this was a comment.

Comment: It was rejected because it should have been a comment to the author indicating the syntax error you found. Or, since you edited with a whole block of code, it could have been it's own answer. Those edits might not even get by our robo-reviewers that @FrédéricHamidi mentioned.

Comment: Well, I wanted to give credit to the guy for having the right concept.  If comments did not mangle code, I would have made it as one.  There seems to be no good way to handle this situation.

Comment: I suppose so.  I don't think it's ideal but I guess I should have done it that way.  I would note that the decision was a split one, 3-2, so not everyone feels that way.

Comment: It was split but, to be fair, the two who approved don't have a very good accept/reject ratio, IMHO. 24/0 and 760/163

Comment: @SteveCohen This is a *very* clear cut example of an edit that should be rejected.  It is most unfortunate that two reviewers accepted such an edit; clearly that don't even know the basics of basics of reviewing edits (despite one of them having reviewed 900 of them).  This is why so many of us have lost faith in the review system.

Comment: @codeMagic Interestingly enough Mik also had a similar ratio and rejected it.  That was a pleasant surprise.  I really was expecting this to go the other way, even though there's no reason at all why it should be approved.

Comment: All right.  I still don't think this is ideal, but I can live with it, now that I understand it.  I just hope you guys understand why I handled it the way I did.  There's logic behind it.

Comment: And done as you all have suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I edit someone else's post I get a notice indicating that my edits will not be visible to others until they are checked by a moderator.

These don't go to mods but to users with 2K+ rep. They are put into a review queue and when users go through them a decision is made. When 3 users accept/reject the edit then the action is taken.

> When can a decision be expected?

Edits usually don't take more than a few minutes to be accepted or rejected but there is no real timeframe for this to be done.

> Will I get notification if my edits are accepted?

Yes, you will be given 2 rep points and get the little notification at the top that you got +2 for an edit.

> Will I get notification if my edits are rejected?

No but you can check the status of your suggestion in your profile.

[image]

Comment: At least I know where to look now.